# How to know the request is preflight and not the actual request?

Tags: javascript, php, cors, cross-domain

I'm using CORS to send data to my server, which is in another domain.

The browser send the first request to check the server (preflight) and later the main request. I'd like to know when the request is "preflighted", so I can return the headers sooner.

I would like something like this:

```
if (isPreflight) {
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
   exit;
} else {
   // handle the main request
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, a preflight request is not only one with the method `OPTIONS`. Three headers need to be present, `Access-Control-Request-Method`, `Access-Control-Request-Headers`, and the `Origin` header.

> A CORS preflight request is a CORS request that checks to see if the
> CORS protocol is understood and a server is aware using specific
> methods and headers.
>
> It is an OPTIONS request, using three HTTP request headers:
> Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, and the
> Origin header.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

I have a method in PHP to identify preflights.

```
function isPreflight() {
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $headers = array_filter($_SERVER, function($item) {
        return preg_match('/^HTTP_/', $item);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

    if (!($method == 'OPTIONS' && isset(
        $headers['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'],
        $headers['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'],
        $headers['HTTP_ORIGIN'])))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Adriano_Pinaffo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72177606/5552686).

This answer is missing the HEADERS sent with preflight requests.

---

Found a way to do this.

Simply put the CORS headers before the "handling data methods" and if the request method is OPTIONS (which is the default preflight method), exit the script, and if it is one of the accepted methods (GET, POST or anything else), handle the data.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "OPTIONS") {
    exit;

} else {
    /*handle data*/
}
```